# Test Coverage for trigger on ActionCadeneSteptracker CDC

Tags: trigger, unit-test, test-setup, sales-cadence, high-velocity-sales

We are working on Updating Lead status on meaningful connect of call in HVS (High Velocity Sales), so we went ahead with the proposed solution of creating CDC on ActionCadenceStepTracker object.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.hvs_cadences_auto_set_lead_value.htm&type=5

Trigger:

```
trigger ActionCadenceStepTrackerCETrigger on 
ActionCadenceStepTrackerChangeEvent (after insert) {

for(ActionCadenceStepTrackerChangeEvent  event : Trigger.New) {
            system.debug('event: '+event);
            EventBus.ChangeEventHeader header = event.ChangeEventHeader;
            List<String> recordIds = header.getRecordIds();
            
            //System.debug('Received change event for ' + header.entityName +' for the '+ header.changeType +' operation.');
            
            if(recordIds.size() == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            
            //Query Metadata records to get queue name and last step of cadence
            Sales_Cadence_Assignment__mdt[] scalist = [SELECT MasterLabel,Parameter1__c,Parameter2__c FROM Sales_Cadence_Assignment__mdt WHERE Type__c = : GlobalConstantCtrl.Cadence_Final_Step];
            
            map<String, String> cadencelaststepmap = new map<String, String>();
            map<String, String> cadencetoQueuemap = new map<String, String>();
            
            for(Sales_Cadence_Assignment__mdt sca : scalist){
                cadencelaststepmap.put(sca.MasterLabel,sca.Parameter1__c);
                cadencetoQueuemap.put(sca.MasterLabel,sca.Parameter2__c);
                
            }
            //Get ActionCadenceStepTracker records for completed steps where the target is a lead
            List<ActionCadenceStepTracker> stepTrackers = [SELECT Id, ActionCadenceStepId, ActionCadenceName, TargetId, StepType, StepTitle
                                                           FROM ActionCadenceStepTracker
                                                           WHERE     Id IN :recordIds 
                                                           AND State = :GlobalConstantCtrl.TASK_STATUS_COMPLETED
                                                           AND Target.Type = :GlobalConstantCtrl.LEAD
                                                           AND StepTitle in :cadencelaststepmap.values()
                                                           AND ActionCadenceName in :cadencelaststepmap.keySet()];
            
            if(stepTrackers != null && stepTrackers.size() > 0) {
                //System.debug('Found ' + stepTrackers.size() + ' step tracker events.');
                
                //Query Queue Id using Queue name derived from Custom metadata
                Group[] queuelist = [select Id, developername from group where developername in :cadencetoQueuemap.values()];
                map<string, Id> queuemap = new map<string, Id>();
                for(group gp : queuelist){
                    queuemap.put(gp.developername, gp.Id);
                }
                List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();
                for(ActionCadenceStepTracker stepTracker : stepTrackers) {
                    System.debug('Adding the lead ID  ' + stepTracker.TargetId + ' to Lead list.');
                    //Add Queue Id derived before as Lead Owner
                    Lead lead = new Lead(Id=stepTracker.TargetId, ownerid=queuemap.get(cadencetoQueuemap.get(stepTracker.ActionCadenceName)));
                    leads.add(lead);
                }
                
                //Update Lead records           
                update leads;
                
            } else {
                System.debug('Did not find any completed First Touch step trackers that are related to leads');
            }
        }
```

We are not able to get test coverage for the CDC trigger.

Test Class:

```
// Enable all Change Data Capture entities for notifications.

    Test.enableChangeDataCapture();

    test.startTest();
    Lead l = new Lead(LastName = 'T1', Status='Open', Email='*****',company='Icc',
                      phone='122', Leadsource='web');
    insert l;
    user u = [select id from user WHERE profile.name='**********' and name='********' and isactive=true limit 1];
    user u1 = [select id from user WHERE username='*****' and isactive=true limit 1];
    l.OwnerId = u.id;
    update l;
    system.runAs(u1){
    Lead l1 = [select ActioncadenceId, Status,Email,id,OwnerId from Lead WHERE id = :l.id];
                   
    // deliver to fire the trigger and deliver event
   // Test.getEventBus().deliver();
    
    Map<String, Object> myMap = new Map<String, Object>();
    myMap.put('Lead_id', l1);
    myMap.put('NewCadenceName', l1.ActioncadenceId);
    // calling flow which assigns lead to sales cadence which will create ActionCadenceStepTracketChangeEvent
    Flow.Interview.Reassign_Lead_to_new_Cadence flowrun = new Flow.Interview.Reassign_Lead_to_new_Cadence(myMap); 
    flowrun.start();
   
    }
    test.stopTest();
```

Please let me know if you have written test class for trigger on `ActionCadenceStepTrackerChangeEvent`

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce StackExchange! Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/343818/edit) your post to explain what you mean by "We are not able to get test coverage...." Are you getting errors? If so, what are the specific errors? Are you just unable to achieve a certain percentage of code coverage (e.g. 75%, 100%)? If so, what lines are and are not covered. Please add your trigger code regardless of the issue.

Comment: @Moonpie i have updated the trigger as well

Comment: You answered one out of one requests, thank you.  But you answered zero out of two questions (each with a follow-up question for a "yes" answer). 'Please edit your post to explain what you mean by "We are not able to get test coverage...." Are you getting errors? If so, what are the specific errors? Are you just unable to achieve a certain percentage of code coverage (e.g. 75%, 100%)? If so, what lines are and are not covered.'

Comment: Hello, Code Coverage is 0%. Object ActionCadenceStepTracker wont support DML statements. So, unable to get coverage. But record can be inserted indirectly using a flow.  and then the trigger is running. i was able to see the trigger getting executed in debug logs. but code coverage was not being shown. If you have experience on High velocity sales, you can know about the object more.

Answer (score 2):

We connected to salesforce support regarding its test class on **ActionCadenceStepTrackerChangeEvent**. The issue that's different than other objects here are:

1. ActionCadenceStepTracker does not support DML(Insert, Update) operation.
2. Test classes don't support callouts
3. ActionCadenceStepTrackerChangeEvent is invoked on DML operation or service call.

We were able to resolve this by publishing dummy events like.

```
   @isTest
public class ActionCadenceStepTrackerChangeTest {
    
    @isTest static void testActionCadenceEvent() {
        Test.enableChangeDataCapture();
        
        // Create mock CREATE change event
        EventBus.ChangeEventHeader createHeader = new EventBus.ChangeEventHeader();
        createHeader.recordIds = new List<String>{ '8HFR00000005BfAOAU' };
        createHeader.changeType='CREATE';
        createHeader.entityName='ActionCadence';
        createHeader.changeOrigin='user1-wsl';
        createHeader.transactionKey = 'key';
        createHeader.commitUser = 'user1';
        ActionCadenceStepTrackerChangeEvent createEvent = new ActionCadenceStepTrackerChangeEvent();
        createEvent.changeEventHeader = createHeader;
        createEvent.put('ActionCadenceId', '77CR0000000ENXAMA4');
        createEvent.put('ActionCadenceStepId', '8C8R00000001rerKAA');
        createEvent.put('State', 'Active');
        createEvent.put('StepType', 'SendAnEmail');
        createEvent.put('StepTitle', 'Email');
        EventBus.publish(createEvent);
        Test.getEventBus().deliver();
        
        // Create mock UPDATE change event
        EventBus.ChangeEventHeader updateHeader = new EventBus.ChangeEventHeader();
        updateHeader.recordIds = new List<String>{ '8HFR00000005BfAOAU' };
        updateHeader.changeType='UPDATE';
        updateHeader.entityName='ActionCadence';
        updateHeader.changeOrigin='user1-wsl';
        updateHeader.transactionKey = 'key';
        updateHeader.commitUser = 'user1';
        ActionCadenceStepTrackerChangeEvent updateEvent = new ActionCadenceStepTrackerChangeEvent();
        updateEvent.changeEventHeader = updateHeader;
        updateEvent.put('State', 'Completed');
        EventBus.publish(updateEvent);
        Test.getEventBus().deliver();
    }  
}
```

In order to cover handlers use Test.isTestRunning() to skip if conditions for *ActionCadenceStepTracker* object refrences.

Please mark this as best answer so that this information can help others.

Answer (score 0):

```apex
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class TestUpdateCustomOnStepCompletionTrigger {

    @isTest 
    static void testActionCadenceEvent() {
        Test.enableChangeDataCapture();
        list<ActionCadenceStepTracker> stepTrackers = [SELECT Id, ActionCadenceStepId, ActionCadenceName,ActionCadenceId, TargetId, StepType,state, StepTitle, ActionTakenDateTime,IsActionTaken
                                                FROM ActionCadenceStepTracker where ActionCadenceStepId!=null and ActionCadenceId!=null and TargetId!=null limit 1];
 
        // Create mock CREATE change event
        EventBus.ChangeEventHeader createHeader = new EventBus.ChangeEventHeader();
        createHeader.recordIds = new List<String>{ '8HFR00000005BfAOAU',stepTrackers[0].id };
        createHeader.changeType='CREATE';
        createHeader.entityName='ActionCadence';
        createHeader.changeOrigin='user1-wsl';
        createHeader.transactionKey = 'key';
        createHeader.commitUser = 'user1';
        ActionCadenceStepTrackerChangeEvent createEvent = new ActionCadenceStepTrackerChangeEvent();
        createEvent.changeEventHeader = createHeader;
        createEvent.put('ActionCadenceId', '77CR0000000ENXAMA4');
        createEvent.put('ActionCadenceStepId', '8C8R00000001rerKAA');
        createEvent.put('State', 'Active');
        createEvent.put('StepType', 'SendAnEmail');
        createEvent.put('StepTitle', 'Email');
        EventBus.publish(createEvent);
        Test.getEventBus().deliver();
        
        // Create mock UPDATE change event
        EventBus.ChangeEventHeader updateHeader = new EventBus.ChangeEventHeader();
        updateHeader.recordIds = new List<String>{ '8HFR00000005BfAOAU',stepTrackers[0].id };
        updateHeader.changeType='UPDATE';
        updateHeader.entityName='ActionCadence';
        updateHeader.changeOrigin='user1-wsl';
        updateHeader.transactionKey = 'key';
        updateHeader.commitUser = 'user1';
        ActionCadenceStepTrackerChangeEvent updateEvent = new ActionCadenceStepTrackerChangeEvent();
        updateEvent.changeEventHeader = updateHeader;
        updateEvent.put('State', 'Completed');
        EventBus.publish(updateEvent);
        Test.getEventBus().deliver();
        
    }  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Thank you for your contribution. Here on SFSE the *why* (explanation) is often as or more important than the *how* (code) in an answer - especially since it can help future searchers/readers. Yyour code is essentially the same as *piyush*'s answer, but with `ActionCadenceStepTracker`s added. Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/384547/edit) your answer to explain enough to understand, what that addition does and why that is beneficial and/or better. Otherwise this is a "code dump" answer, which are often downvoted.